# task scheduler does not run when not logged in

Tags: windows-server-2008, vb6

I have created simple exe to perform a task using VB6. I have deployed the same on Windows Server 2008 as task scheduler. The issue is when the user is not logged in on server, task fails to execute.

I have kept option to "Run whether user is logged on or not", still no use.

Comment: Does this exe have a User Interface?  I am having a similar problem with a Qt application with a user interface.

Comment: This might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/101671/scheduled-tasks-w-gui-issue

Comment: Exe does not have Interface. I will check the suggested solution and see if that helps. THanks for the link.